# How do I append an element to the beginning of a list after splitting a list?

Tags: prolog

I'm a total Prolog noob and I'm having some trouble with my code.

I'm trying to split a list into two using an inputted element. The list will split into a left list that will have everything before the element and a right list that will have everything after the element, including the element

I know that `split(List, Split, Left, Right) :- append(Left, [Split | Right], List),` with return

```
?- split( [3,5,6,8,10,4,5], 10, Left, Right).
Left = [3, 5, 6, 8],
Right = [4, 5]
```

However, my desired result is:

```
?-split( [3,5,6,8,10,4,5], 10, Left, Right).
  Left = [3,5,6,8]  
  Right = [**10**,4,5]
```

I've tried to use an append to get the 10 to the beginning of the Right List but it returns false and I don't know why. Here's the code I'e tried:

```
split(List, Split, Left, Right) :- 
    append(Left, [Split | RightTemp], List), 
    append(Split, RightTemp, Right).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be surprised how easy the solution is. :)

```
split(List, Split, Left, [Split|Right]) :- 
    append(Left, [Split|Right], List).
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I'm a bit annoyed I over thought it that much. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I know this wasn't in the original question but how can I do this if there's no valid split. For example, ?-split( [3,5,6], 10, Left, Right). -> Left= [3,5,6], Right=[ ]?

Comment: @Asian_Ninja1 precede the append call with `memberchk(Split, List), `. Then it will fail if the split element is not present in the list.

Comment: Thank you! You've been a great help